# Layout xml changes aren't being applied

Tags: layout, xml

I want to remove element from `catalog.xml`, but no matter what I will change in this file (and in other `xml` files too), changes will not apply to site. I can even delete whole `catalog.xml` code, and after flushing the cache there is still no changes. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: I was searching in wrong `xml`-file. But different answers on stackexchange was saying about `catalog.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a layout xml file.  It can live in several places, depending on your version and theme

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/layout/catalog.xml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout/catalog.xml
```

Check all these areas.